Correctly implement async DeviceIoControl as task?
For reading CD-ROMs using DeviceIoControl and SPTD, I upgraded the code to be asynchronous.
It works but I'm not totally sure on how correct translation from OVERLAPPED to Task actually is...
Here is the relevant code,
ReadSectorAsync:
public override unsafe Task<ISector> ReadSectorAsync(in int index)
{
    using var manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(true);

    var overlapped = new Overlapped
    {
        EventHandleIntPtr = manualResetEvent.SafeWaitHandle.DangerousGetHandle(),
    };

    var nativeOverlapped = overlapped.Pack(null, null);

    var memory = Disc.GetDeviceAlignedBuffer(2352, Handle);

    var buffer = memory.Span;

    const int timeOutValue = 3;

    fixed (byte* data = &MemoryMarshal.GetReference(buffer))
    {
        var inBufferSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf<NativeTypes.SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT>();
        var inBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)inBufferSize);

        var position = index;

        // ReSharper disable once ConvertToConstant.Local
        var transfer = 1u; // sectors

        var sptd = new NativeTypes.SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT(12)
        {
            Length             = (ushort)inBufferSize,
            DataIn             = NativeConstants.SCSI_IOCTL_DATA_IN,
            DataTransferLength = (uint)buffer.Length,
            DataBuffer         = (nint)data,
            TimeOutValue       = timeOutValue,
            Cdb =
            {
                [00] = 0xBE,                          // operation code: READ CD
                [01] = 0,                             // expected sector type: any
                [02] = (byte)(position >> 24 & 0xFF), // starting LBA
                [03] = (byte)(position >> 16 & 0xFF), // starting LBA
                [04] = (byte)(position >> 08 & 0xFF), // starting LBA
                [05] = (byte)(position >> 00 & 0xFF), // starting LBA
                [06] = (byte)(transfer >> 16 & 0xFF), // transfer length
                [07] = (byte)(transfer >> 08 & 0xFF), // transfer length
                [08] = (byte)(transfer >> 00 & 0xFF), // transfer length
                [09] = 0xF8,                          // sync, header, sub-header, user data, EDC, ECC
                [10] = 0,                             // sub-channel data: none
                [11] = 0,                             // control
            },
        };

        Marshal.StructureToPtr(sptd, inBuffer, false);

        var ioctl = NativeMethods.DeviceIoControl(
            Handle,
            NativeConstants.IOCTL_SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT,
            inBuffer,
            inBufferSize,
            inBuffer,
            inBufferSize,
            out _,
            nativeOverlapped
        );

        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(inBuffer);

        if (ioctl is false && Marshal.GetLastPInvokeError() is not NativeConstants.ERROR_IO_PENDING)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }
    }

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<ISector>();

    var rwh = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(
        manualResetEvent,
        ReadSectorAsyncCallBack,
        (tcs, memory),
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOutValue),
        true
    );

    tcs.Task.ContinueWith(_ => rwh.Unregister(null), TaskScheduler.Current);

    return tcs.Task;
}

ReadSectorAsyncCallBack:
private void ReadSectorAsyncCallBack(object? state, bool timedOut)
{
    var (source, memory) = ((TaskCompletionSource<ISector>, NativeMemory<byte>))state!;

    try
    {
        if (timedOut)
        {
            source.SetCanceled();
        }
        else
        {
            ISector sector = Sector switch
            {
                SectorCooked2048       => throw new NotSupportedException(Sector.GetType().Name),
                SectorCooked2324       => throw new NotSupportedException(Sector.GetType().Name),
                SectorCooked2336       => throw new NotSupportedException(Sector.GetType().Name),
                SectorRawAudio         => MemoryMarshal.Read<SectorRawAudio>(memory.Span),
                SectorRawMode0         => MemoryMarshal.Read<SectorRawMode0>(memory.Span),
                SectorRawMode1         => MemoryMarshal.Read<SectorRawMode1>(memory.Span),
                SectorRawMode2Form1    => MemoryMarshal.Read<SectorRawMode2Form1>(memory.Span),
                SectorRawMode2Form2    => MemoryMarshal.Read<SectorRawMode2Form2>(memory.Span),
                SectorRawMode2FormLess => MemoryMarshal.Read<SectorRawMode2FormLess>(memory.Span),
                _                      => throw new NotSupportedException(Sector.GetType().Name),
            };

            source.SetResult(sector);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        source.SetException(e);
    }
    finally
    {
        memory.Dispose();
    }
}

